# Zenity from command line Linux installation

Tags: 12.04, command-line, software-installation, gtk, zenity

I have a command line installation of Linux,  i.e. when I was installing it, I chose to install a command line version.

I want to make use of zenity from the command line to popup dialog boxes etc. I've installed zenity, but when I try to use it, I get a gtk error:

```
(zenity:22955): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
xf_pre_connect: failed to open display:
Please check that the $DISPLAY environment variable is properly set.
```

Is it not possible to get zenity to work from a command line installation of Linux?

Comment: What happens if you do an `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then retry?

Comment: I get `(zenity:908): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0`.  Don't I need to install xorg or something like that?

Comment: What do you get when you try to `sudo apt-get install xorg`?

Comment: It installed about 70+ MB or packages.  I tried zenity again and got the same error message again.  I got similar messages with and without the export.

Comment: Are you on a desktop or a server? Are you accessing a remote machine with `ssh` where you run this zenity command?

Comment: I'm on a desktop, but have no gui, just the command line.  No, I am not accessing a remote machine with ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zenity need a graphical environment (X server) to run.

Have a look at [whiptail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/whiptail.1.html) (package `whiptail`) or [dialog](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dialog.1.html) (package `dialog`) if you want to display dialog boxes in text mode.